# Build a RESTful API server using FLASK?

Tags: python, api, flask-restful

I have a python function which takes a JSON object as an input and returns a 'YES/NO' output. Now, I am trying to convert it into an API server, so that another API can call it, pass the JSON and my API server can return a 'YES/NO'.

I read about Flask-RESTFul and looked at few examples. But all of them are written from the perspective of API client, like an API to read a todo list or read data from a db etc.

Could someone give an example of 2 small scripts - one acting as an API server and another acting as an API client. The API client calls the API server and passes on the following JSON -

```
{'fruit_1':'apple', 'fruit_2':'melon'}
```

and the API server returns 'apple' as an output.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried searching for existing tutorials elsewhere on the Internet first like http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/quickstart.html

Comment: Hi metatoaster!
Yes, I read this quickstart guide. It talks about building an API client for an todo web service. A short concrete example would be helpful.

Comment: @Amit Did code given below not work? You can use Flask Restful with classes and get, post methods etc but this is simplest example. I forgot to mention request POST

Comment: @Zohaib - Thank you for your response. I will test it and update in some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample Restful api code.

## server side code

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class MyResource(Resource):
    def post(self):
        data = request.data
        # Process data
        return {'message': 'YES/NO'}

api.add_resource(MyResource, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## client side code

```
import json
import requests
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
data = json.dumps({'fruit_1':'apple', 'fruit_2':'melon'})
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
print(response.json()['message'])
```

Comment: Tried the code...it worked after a small tweak. Please make these changes, so that I can accept your answer.
1. include 'from flask import request' in the server side code.

And thank you so much for the help.
One more question - is this the RESTful API ?